# Undefined variable inside Jinja2 loop - trying to access an index

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a main playbook that runs 3 other playbooks as part of my termination process for users. This is the plabook:

```
---
- name: "Playbook: Terminate user"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: True

  roles:
   - { role: common, tags: ['always'] }
   - { role: terminate_user, tags: ['terminate_user', 'never'] }

- name: "Playbook: Terminate storage"
  hosts: storage
  gather_facts: False
  roles:
   - { role: terminate_storage, tags: ['terminate_storage', 'always'] }

- name: "Playbook: User environment"
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  roles:
    - { role: common,
        tags: ['always'],
      }

    - { role: send_email,
        tags: ['send_email', 'always']
      }
```

I'm trying to print out the `storage` playbook's output in my `send_email` playbook. It looks like this:

```
- name: Logical block of home-storage tasks
  block:
  - name: Check if home folder exists
    stat:
      path: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].fspath }}/{{ username }}"
    register: home_dir_details

  - name: Move user home folder to terminated home folder
    command: mv {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].fspath }}/{{ username }} "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].fspath }}/terminated/{{ username }}"
    when: home_dir_details.stat.exists
    register: storage_moved

  - name: Printing and debugging
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      msg: "{{ storage_moved }}"
  when: 
    - hostvars[inventory_hostname].fsname is search("home")
```

In the email template, I'm printing the `storage_moved` variable like this:

```
{% for host in groups['storage'] %}
{{ hostvars[host]['storage_moved'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

The output looks good, it's exactly what I see in the playbook's run (the first one was skipped on purpose):

```
{'changed': False, 'skipped': True, 'skip_reason': 'Conditional result was False'} 
{'changed': True, 'end': '2021-10-21 12:47:13.363691', 'stdout': '', 'cmd': ['mv', '/path/user', '/path/terminated/user'], 'rc': 0, 'start': '2021-10-21 12:47:13.357842', 'stderr': '', 'delta': '0:00:00.005849', 'stdout_lines': [], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False}
```

In my `storage` hosts, I only have 2 servers configured, so printing 2 dictionaries looks ok.

My problem is that when I try to access the `cmd` variable, I'm not able to or don't know how. For example, I thought this should work:

```
{% for host in groups['storage'] %}
{{ hostvars[host]['storage_moved'][loop.index] }}
{% endfor %}
```

I get an error: `"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: dict object has no element 1`

So I tried something like this:

```
{% for host in groups['storage'] %}
{{ hostvars[host]['storage_moved']['cmd'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

But it doesn't work as well, I get the following error: `"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'cmd'`.

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to access that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> {'changed': False, 'skipped': True, 'skip_reason': 'Conditional result was False'} 
> {'changed': True, 'end': '2021-10-21 12:47:13.363691', 'stdout': '', 'cmd': ['mv', '/path/user', '/path/terminated/user'], 'rc': 0, 'start': '2021-10-21 12:47:13.357842', 'stderr': '', 'delta': '0:00:00.005849', 'stdout_lines': [], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False}
> ```

Have a closer look at the first output result in your example loop, the one returned from a skipped task: do you see a `cmd` attribute anywhere ? Well, answer is: no. So the error your report is actually expected.

You need to manage the cases where the attribute you are looking for is not present. One easy solution is to provide a default value but you can find you own depending on your exact requirement.

```
{% for host in groups['storage'] %}
{{ hostvars[host]['storage_moved']['cmd'] | default('No command was played') }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, misread your question. Let me try again. :) In your example you provide this:

```
{'changed': False, 'skipped': True, 'skip_reason': 'Conditional result was False'} 
{'changed': True, 'end': '2021-10-21 12:47:13.363691', 'stdout': '', 'cmd': ['mv', '/path/user', '/path/terminated/user'], 'rc': 0, 'start': '2021-10-21 12:47:13.357842', 'stderr': '', 'delta': '0:00:00.005849', 'stdout_lines': [], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False}
```

Your first result documents a skipped task and therefore the dictionary does not contain a `cmd` key.

Try changing to this:

```
{% for host in groups['storage'] %}
{{ hostvars[host]['storage_moved']['cmd'] | default('skipped') }}
{% endfor %}
```

The `default` filter will supply a value in the case that the specified variable is undefined. Does that improve things?

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work.  I'm not sure if it's needed because I can access the `storage moved` variable, but I'm not sure how to access the variables inside `{{ hostvars[host]['storage_moved'] }}`. For example, as per the output I posted, I would like to access `cmd` which is a variable inside the `{{ hostvars[host]['storage_moved'] }}` loop.

Comment: Apologies - misread the Q, so have edited my answer to hopefully be a little more helpful.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but 10 minutes ago (as of writing this), that was the exact solution by @Zeitounator :)

Comment: Ah fair play @Zeitounator  - had the Q open in edit mode whilst on a call and didn't see you already had the answer. Glad you got sorted. :)